# How can I force a non constant iterator from std::list.begin()?

Tags: c++

I am working on the implementation of a multiset amd am using a list as its underlying data container. I have a function count which returns the number of occurrences of an item in the private list. Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class miniMultiSet
{
    public:

    typedef typename list<T>::iterator iterator; // miniMultiSet iterators are simply list iterators
    typedef typename list<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    miniMultiSet(){} // default constructor

    bool empty() const // is the multiset empty?
    {return l.empty();}

    int size() const // return the number of elements in the multiset
    {return l.size();}

    int count (const T& item) const
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (*it == item)
                cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    //other member functions

    private:
    list<T> l;// multiset implemented using a list  
};
```

Upon compilation including the use of `count` I get the following error (The call was from an instance where `T` is `string`):

```
error: conversion from 'std::list<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >}' to non-scalar type 'miniMultiSet<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >}' requested
```

on the `for` line inside of `count` which makes me think that `iterator it = l.begin()` is causing a problem trying to convert from constant to non constant.

Is that what is happening?

Is there a way I can adjust that loop or force a non constant return of `l.begin()`?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use a `const_iterator`?

Comment: Your "count () const" is const instances compatible. 
So use the const_iterator returns a reference to a constant value (const T&) and prevents modification of the referenced value. It enforces const-correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is that what is happening?"*

Well, the signature you give just applies for `const` class instances compatibility

```
 int count (const T& item) const {
                        // ^^^^^
```

> *"Is there a way I can adjust that loop or force a non constant return of `l.begin()`?"*

In particular for *`or force a non constant return`*, no you can't, and you certainly don't want to for this operation. You should simply use a `const_iterator` in your loop:

```
int count (const T& item) const {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (const_iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) { 
      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (*it == item)
            cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: That did it but what is constant about it if I can still increment it through the loop?

Comment: @Evan `const_iterator`s can be incremented as any other, the difference comes, when you're going to dereference them. The `const` versions don't allow you to modify the value the iterator points to. Since you're not trying to do such (modifying) operation in your function, the `const_iterator` is well sufficient here.